# Convert Mjpeg to jpg with php and curl

Tags: php, html, curl, video-streaming, mjpeg

I want to display video stream in a video html tag of a camera filming things.

I have to connect to the camera with authentication, so I use curl. I managed to do it and to retrieve the stream.
Now I have to treat it.
I get this stream JPEG images. Except that, no way, to convert datas in pictures.

Here is part of my test code to display one image:

```
$_SESSION['img'] = "";
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://$ip/cgi-bin/mjpg/video.cgi'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, '$user:$pass');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, function($ch, $str) use ($i) {
    $pos = strpos($str, '--myboundary');

    if ($pos !== FALSE && strlen($_SESSION['img']) > 0) {
        //Complete the image data
        $imagePart = substr($str, 0, $pos-1);
        $_SESSION['img'] .= $imagePart;

        //Parse data
        $imgstr = str_replace("--myboundary\r\n", '', $_SESSION['img']);
        $imgstr = str_replace("Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", '', $imgstr);
        $imgstr = str_replace("Content-Length: ", '', $imgstr);
        $imgstr = preg_replace("/\d+\r\n\r\n/", '', $imgstr);

        //save in file - file not loaded
        file_put_contents('img/test.jpg', $imgstr);

        //generate image - doesn't work 
        $im = imagecreatefromstring($imgstr);
        if ($im !== false) {
            header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
            imagejpeg($im);
            imagedestroy($im);
        }

        session_destroy();
        die();
    }

    $_SESSION['img'] .= $str;

    return strlen($str);

}); 

$output = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

If you have ideas, let me know!

Thank you